# Matching two different lines that are at least N lines distant from each other

Tags: sed, grep, awk

I would like to match files that contain `try` (in one line) and consecutive `catch` (in another line) **at least N lines later** (to find very long try-catches and try to get rid of them). I mean, the *first* `catch` after `try` should be be N lines later.

Is there a good way to do this with standard UNIX tools like `grep`, `sed`, `awk`?

I experimented with doing twice `grep -A <number> -B <number>` but it's good at the reverse thing, i.e. finding the try-catches that are not longer than N lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this solution?

```
awk -v gap=5 '
       /try/ {inside=1; a=0; next}
       inside{a++}
      /catch/ && inside && (a>=gap) {print "line",NR, "gap of",a,$0; inside=0}
' file
```

#### Explanation

- `-v gap=5` gives the gap size. If there are some try/catch whose lines are in a distance bigger than this, they will be printed.
- `/try/ {inside=1; a=0; next}` if the line contains a `try`, then the counter begins. `inside` is the flag that means we are checking a `try/catch`. `a` is the counter of lines.
- `inside{a++}` if we are inside, ++ the counter while reading a line.
- `/catch/ && inside && (a>gap)` if the line contains a "catch" and we are inside the "try" condition and the counter is bigger than what we set with `gap`, then do `{print "line",NR, "gap of",a,$0; inside=0}`.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello
try
line1
catch

blabla
try
line1
line2
line3
line4
catch
end
```

With a gap of 5:

```
$ awk -v gap=5 '/try/ {inside=1; a=0; next} inside{a++} /catch/ && inside && (a>=gap) {print "line",NR, "gap of",a,$0; inside=0}' a
line 12 gap of 5 catch
```

With a gap of 2:

```
$ awk -v gap=2 '/try/ {inside=1; a=0; next} inside{a++} /catch/ && inside && (a>=gap) {print "line",NR, "gap of",a,$0; inside=0}' a
line 4 gap of 2 catch
line 12 gap of 5 catch
```